# Elasticsearch - How to sum the values ​from each new document into a separate index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, efk

Example:

My documents:

```
{"_id":"1", "data_sent":"100"}
{"_id":"2", "data_sent":"110"}
{"_id":"3", "data_sent":"120"}
```

I would like to get value of `'data_sent'` for every new document and sum it up to another index, lets say

```
index_name: 'data_sum'
field: 'total_data_sent'='330'
```

**Bonus:** I would like to create new indexes automatically for specified time period (for example `/week`)

I know that aggregations can be used here, but as I understand they are performed when the request is sent and for big data it could last for a while. I need to receive those data very fast when its needed.

Is there anything in Elastic that could help in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by diving deeper into documentation.

`'Transforms'` was that I was looking for.

**https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/transform-overview.html**